# Does "As far as character goes, she is a really interesting person." mean that regarding character, this person is an interesting person?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

What about, "**As far as interests go**, I love gardening and sewing." and "**As far as looks go**, she is very cute." ? Does '**as far as something goes/go**' mean '**regarding that thing**'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as X goes...

This type of phrase limits the next statement to the area or domain of X.

> As far as smell goes, it's very pleasant, but it tastes terrible.

Or it is just a  phrase to orient the listener to the subject the speaker is about to address:

> As far as cars go, I prefer one with all-wheel drive.

A variant of this phrase is "When it comes to".

> When it comes to cars, I prefer one with all-wheel drive.

Comment: So the sentences I have given as examples are correct as they fall under the second category (orienting the listener to a subject), right?

Comment: @M.Vohra As a learner, I think you can also use this pattern: as far as ..... is concerned, ...

Comment: Absent additional context, it is orientation. But one could say, "As far as looks go, she is very cute, but she has no sense of humor." and in that case, it would be more than orientation; it would be setting up the contrast, and in that case, **looks** would be likely to receive a special intonation and emphasis.

Comment: Understood but there is something I want to reconfirm. My examples are right when I want to introduce the reader to a particular subject (character, interest or looks), right?

Comment: @M.Vohra Not quite -- you use this to *restrict* what you are going to say to a subject, or a particular aspect of the subject; as TRomano says, it is often used to set up a contrast with what you have to say about another subject or aspect.